# Apache proxypass or rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, proxypass

I'm actually developping a small php website (only php, no java) and I would like to figure out something.

When I have this url called URL A: http://www.domain.com/?toto, everything's working
I would like to rewrite it to http://www.domain.com/toto (called URL B) but when I tried, I have a 404 page not found.

What do I have to use to tell apache, when you have URL B it's an alias of URL A ??

It tried proxypass, Rewrite rules without reaching my aim. Can someone help me please?

Thx a lot !!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Apache's `mod_rewrite`.

A simple rewrite rule can be placed in your .htaccess file (untested):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: UPDATE: changed the `RewriteRule` - had it backwards (oops).

Comment: I finally reach what I want to do and here is the result:
# Rewrite for http://domain.com/index.php?action=11111
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]  

#Rewrite back
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*) /\?$1=$2 [END]